How to install certain packages that are not available inside a container environment
I am working on tekton pipeline and I am trying to build my Dockerfile inside a running container (i.e., dind), but it's not able to find a few packages inside the container environment.
#No match for argument: lsscsi
#No match for argument: nvme-cli
#No match for argument: nfs-utils

#Dockerfile
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-init

RUN yum -y update \
    && yum -y install \
              lsscsi \
              nvme-cli \
              net-tools

#Rest of Dockerfile

On the base container, I have enabled epel repo, attached redhat subscription and enabled few other repos, but still it does not work.
I have written a script and execute this script before the docker build takes place
#!/bin/bash
subscription-manager register --username --password
subscription-manager attach
subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-$(arch)-rpms
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-8-for-$(arch)-baseos-rpms
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-8-for-$(arch)-appstream-rpms
yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

When I build this on rhel8 system, it uses the host's subscription and it is successfully able to install those packages, but only inside container env it fails. Is there some way I can work it to install inside a container?
Also am I missing out enabling any ubi specific repos?

The issue occurs because the UBI8 container doesn't automatically use the same repositories as the host. To fix it, register the container with the Red Hat Subscription Manager using
subscription-manager register --username=<your_username> --password=<your_password> 

and attach the subscription with
subscription-manager attach

Then, enable the required repositories with
subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-$(arch)-rpms --enable rhel-8-for-$(arch)-baseos-rpms --enable rhel-8-for-$(arch)-appstream-rpms

Finally, install EPEL inside the container using
 yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

